# max.poll.records in conjunction with fetch.min.bytes

Tags: apache-kafka

I am reading this [How does max.poll.records affect the consumer poll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308986/how-does-max-poll-records-affect-the-consumer-poll), as well as apache kafka docs, and I am still not sure if `fetch.min.bytes` is not changed, and the default is 1, is kafka broker obligated to return `max.poll.records` of records, if that much is available, or not?

According to our tests, it does not always return that much even if there is sufficient data available in a topic, and the explanation of that parameter from documentation and its sheer name does not imply it should, but some people tend to think the opposite. We also increased the limits that could potentially prevent this from happen, like `message.max.bytes`, `max.message.bytes`, `max.partition.fetch.bytes`, and `fetch.max.bytes` (that one we actually didn't have to increase, since the default is rather high, 50 MB), but that didn't change a thing.

We also didn't change `fetch.max.wait.ms`, and default is 500, that is a half of a second, so, if `fetch.min.bytes` is not set to something more than 1 byte, then this setting becomes effective, ie, it determines how much records is actually returned? Which would mean that if less then `max.poll.records` was returned, it is because it would take more than 500 ms to fetch that much?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

These 2 configurations can be confusing and while at first sight they look similar they work in very different ways.

- `fetch.min.bytes`: This value is one of the fields of Fetch Requests (it's `min_bytes` in http://kafka.apache.org/protocol#The_Messages_Fetch). This value is used by the broker to decide when to send a Fetch Response back to the client. When a broker receives a Fetch Request it can hold it for up to `fetch.max.wait.ms` if there are not `fetch.min.bytes` bytes available for consumption (for example the consumer is at the end of the log or the messages to be consumed add to less than that size).
- `max.poll.records`: This setting is only used within the Consumer and is never sent to brokers. In the background (asynchronously), the consumer client actively fetches records from the broker and buffers them so when `poll()` is called, it can return records already fetched. As the name suggest, this settings control how many records at most `poll()` can return from the consumer buffer.

Comment: Very good explanation!!! Thank you so much @Mickael Maison

Comment: Does fetch.min.bytes correspond to a single partition or all the partitions in the consumer request?

Comment: Ok, I guess fetch.min.bytes means the minimum data for all the partitions that in the consumer request

Comment: Can we say the `fetch.min.bytes` property can be used to batch the requests. I mean the broker will send more than 1 messages. For example `fetch.min.bytes` is set to 5MB and each message is of approx. 1 MB then the broker will send 5 messages in a single request.

Comment: What about max.partition.fetch.bytes ? does this property limit fetch.min.bytes ?